# Background creation of BufferedImage and synchronization with Semaphores

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, semaphore, bufferedimage

I have a background thread that produces pixels of an image (suppose a `java.awt.image.BufferedImage`) in a top-down left-right fashion and I want the Swing gui to paint the available portion of the image at regular intervals, to show progress to the user.
As far as I undertood from many answers, `BufferedImage` is not thread-safe so I'm wondering if it's possible to use a `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore` to enforce synchronization and memory consistency. The background thread would call `release()` on the semaphore after every pixel write operation while a `javax.swing.Timer` would call `drainPermits()` on the semaphore and request the returned number of pixels to be painted. I guess this scheme should work because the documentation of `Semaphore` states that:

> Actions in a thread prior to calling a "release" method such as `release()` *happen-before* actions following a successful "acquire" method such as `acquire()` in another thread.

Please tell me if I am correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore`, consider using a `javax.swing.Timer` in the model to periodically notify the observing view, and synchronize access to the evolving `BufferedImage`. If your model is `Observable`, you can use the optional `arg` in `notifyObservers()` to pass boundary information. A complete example is examined [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/threadwatch).

Comment: I can't understand why in the example posted some of the accesses to the `BufferedImage` are synchronized while others are not. See the `next()` method in class `Model` and the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method in class `View`.

Comment: Good question: `next()` is invoked _only_ on the model thread, while `getImage()` in the view is invoked on the EDT.

Comment: Ok next() is invoked only on the model thread but the pixels it writes are concurrently read from another thread. What makes those writes visible?

Comment: `public synchronized BufferedImage getImage() {…}`?

Comment: But that would only synchronize access to the reference field, not to the contents of the image...

Comment: As well as `Raster` updates that happen before the synchronization point. If this is not sufficient, consider this alternate [approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16880714/230513) that publishes a `Raster` from a `SwingWorker` in the form of a `TexturePaint`.