# Crosshatched bar chart with JFreeChart

Tags: jfreechart, bar-chart

I need to plot a horizontal bar chart using JFreeChart. The problem is that some specific itens need to appear with a crosshatched fill (or any other visual style that makes clear that the item is different from the rest). Please see the piture below.

I couldn't find anything in XYBarRenderer to help me....

Does anyone know how to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I couldn't find anything in `XYBarRenderer` to help.

Right, [`XYBarRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYBarRenderer.html) uses an instance of `GradientBarPainter` to render each bar. You can replace it with your own `BarPainter` to render a bar however you like. `TexturePaint`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16880714/230513), would be a good choice.