# Tile Background

Tags: java, image, swing, background, jframe

I would like to add a background image to my JFrame. I would like it to be a tile background that repeats depending on how big the JFrame is.

for example:

(I do not own the images in these links)

I have created an image which you can see here:
[image: Background tile]

Unfortunately my JFrame is too big for this image. So instead of making a entirely new image I would like to repeat this image to fill the screen.

Currently this is my program:

```
package main;

import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Game {

    public static void main(String [ ] args) {
        Run();

    }

    public static void Run() {
        //Create window
        JFrame Game = new JFrame("Infinite Doom " + Launcher.STATE + " " + Launcher.VER);
        Game.pack();

        //Window Settings
        Game.setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        Game.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("res/Logo.png").getImage()); 

        //set visible
        Game.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: This is a poorly asked question. could you please add some information, like what you have done?

Comment: Please show some code, show some images, and describe in a little more detail just what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a [`java.awt.TexturePaint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TexturePaint.html), illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16880714/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11556441/230513), constructed using a `BufferedImage` containing your `Logo.png`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/). It allows you to tile images.