# Tileing image on JPanel, java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a method to set the 'texture' of a `JPanel`, however it is throwing a `NullPointerException`, and i cannot figure out why.

Method:

```
void setTexutre(Image tileImage) {
    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
    int width = (int) getBounds().getWidth();
    int height = (int) getBounds().getHeight();
    int imageW = tileImage.getWidth(panel);
    int imageH = tileImage.getHeight(panel);
    for (int x5 = 0; x5 < width; x5 += imageW) {
        for (int y5 = 0; y5 < height; y5 += imageH) {
            g.drawImage(tileImage, x5, y5, panel);
        }
    }
    panel.paint(g);
}
```

The `NullPointerException` is thrown when i call "g.drawImage(tileImage, x5, y5, panel);"

And yes, the image is a real image, i have checked. In the method above `panel` is defined as a new `JPanel`, and intializes normally when I do not call the method.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Use `TexturePaint`, as shown in the examples cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24746585/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. DON'T use `Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();`
2. NEVER call `panel.paint(g);`

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works in Swing/AWT.

`getGraphics` may return `null` (it's even documented as saying so) and you SHOULD never rely on it, it's not how custom painting works.  Instead, you should override the components `paintComponent` method and perform your custom painting within it.

You don't control the paint process and should never call `paint` directly, Swing uses a passive rendering algorithm, this means that components are update ad-hoc, when ever the `RepaintManager` decides that they need to be repainted.  This means, even if you could get your current code to work, the moment the `RepaintManager` decides to repaint `panel`, all you rendering would be lost...

Answer (score -1):

The following is the class I used for anyone else looking at this question.

```
package i.am.not.posting.the.real.pack.name;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TiledPanel extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage tileImage;

    public TiledPanel(BufferedImage tileImage) {
        this.tileImage = tileImage;
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        int imageW = tileImage.getWidth();
        int imageH = tileImage.getHeight();
        // Tile the image to fill our area.
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x += imageW) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y += imageH) {
                g.drawImage(tileImage, x, y, this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

simply creating a TilePanel object will correctly tile the image.

Comment: You've broken the paint chain - See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for details about how painting works in Swing

Comment: Why downvote? And what do you mean I have broken the paint chain? 1. It works, 2. I did see that tutorial.

Comment: It's downvoted because it's a bad example of how to perform custom painting. It might "work" but it's at risk of allowing paint artefacts to remain within the graphics context and/or encourage bad practice which could lead to further paint artefacts

Comment: 1. Artefacts = Art**i**facts, 2. would it be fixed if i added super.paintComponent?